# Как переделать часы:минуты в TimePickerDialog на минуты:секунды

Tags: android, dialogfragment

Как можно переделать TimePickerDialog, чтобы вместо того чтобы он выставлял часы и минуты, он стал выставлять минуты и секунды?

Можно это сделать простым способом?

Или нужно создавать свой класс, наследоваться от TimePickerDialog и уже переписывать код под себя.

Comment: судя по этому запросу в гугл https://www.google.dk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android+TimePickerDialog+minutes+and+seconds&es_th=1 прогстого способа нет.

Comment: вот может стоит воспользоваться готовым решением - [TimePickerWithSeconds](https://github.com/IvanKovac/TimePickerWithSeconds)

Comment: Я хотел чтобы он отображался в стиле Material Design. То что вы предлагаете я сделал с помощью NumberPiker'ов. Но хотелось бы изменить это оформление